# The following UDF is restarted over and over again in Excel 2007

Tags: vba, excel

The following UDF works well in Excel 2013, but in excel 2007 it is restarted over and over again, when I run a macro to unhide all rows in a sheet:

```
Function VisibleBlankCells(R As Range) As Long
    'On Error Resume Next
    'VisibleBlankCells = Intersect(r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)).Count
    'On Error GoTo 0

    Dim count As Long
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In R
        If c.Value = "" And c.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next c

    VisibleBlankCells = count
End Function
```

The last row evaluated is `If c.Value = "" And c.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then` then the debugger jumps back to `Function VisibleBlankCells(R As Range) As Long`. What could be the reason for this? How can I fix it?

Comment: do you use it in vba code or in excel cell?

Comment: The code is used in an Excel cell

Comment: After having this code run in an Excel cell, do you run a macro that unhides rows (and triggers recalculation every time)?

Answer (score 0):

Add Application.calculation=xlCalculationManual at the start of your macro and reset using Application.Calculation=xlCalculationAutomatic at the end of your macro